# Recursive fetching of a connection is rejected by Relay. Reproducible on the Relay playground

Tags: recursion, relayjs

One more try with the same issue as here https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1243. But this time I made it reproducible on the Relay playground.

The idea is to fetch data recursively when a user hovers over a parent category.

I've made two gists. One with the schema and the second with the app. Just copy and paste them into the playground, hover over the catName2 and you'll get the error.

The schema https://gist.github.com/GrigoryPtashko/d110b72076a4611657d5364109ba5905.

The app https://gist.github.com/GrigoryPtashko/c27d6421f1f02c78dc054b2874b4ac87.

The problem is when the inner fragment is included and data-fetched the Relay "rejects" the data that comes back from the backend.

When I wrote the first issue, I thought that this is some issue with my graphql backend (it is not in JS). But now I made it reproducible without even the backend.

Seems to me this is none the less a bug.

Thanks.

PS Here's the schema and the app pasted into the [relay playgroud](http://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getCategory(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20id%2C%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bid%7D%60%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getCategories(category)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20cats%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%200%3B%20idx%20%3C%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cats.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20category.id%20%2B%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bcategory.id%20%2B%20idx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20cats%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20getCategory(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20categoryType%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20categoryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Category'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(category%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(getCategories(category)%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20categoryConnection%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Category'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20categoryType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20getCategory(args.id)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%7D)%3B&source=class%20CategoryRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category(id%3A%20%24id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20paramDefinitions%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%20required%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'CategoryRoute'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItemSubCategoryList%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.categories.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node.hasChildren%20%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3CCategoryItemContainer%20key%3D%7Bnode.id%7D%20category%3D%7Bnode%7D%2F%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3E%7Bnode.name%7D%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20))%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItemSubCategoryList%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20categories(first%3A%2010000)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemContainer.getFragment('category')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItem%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%20%20relay%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20category%20%3D%20this.props.category%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onMouseOver%3D%7Bthis.openCategory.bind(this)%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3E%7Bcategory.name%7D%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.relay.variables.expanded%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20key%3D%7Bcategory.id%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20categories%3D%7Bcategory.categories%7D%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20openCategory()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20expanded%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItem%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20expanded%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20(variables)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment('categories').if(variables.expanded)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BCategoryItemContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20CategoryRoute(%7B%20id%3A%20'2'%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20renderFetched%3D%7B(data)%20%3D%3E%20%3CCategoryItemContainer%20%7B...data%7D%2F%3E%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you've encountered is `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. This is because the `categories` prop passed in here is undefined:

```js
<CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer 
  categories={this.props.category.categories}
  key={this.props.category.id}
/>
```

The problem is that you've expected a `categories` prop to materialize on the data supplied to `CategoryItem` by Relay. Taking a look at the fragment for `CategoryItem` though…

```js
fragments: {
  category: variables => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Category {
      id
      name
      ${CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer
        .getFragment('categories')
        .if(variables.expanded)
      }
    }
  `,
},
```

You can see that `categories` is nowhere to be found. It's included via `CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment(…)`, for sure, but since `CategoryItem` has not fetched it explicitly, Relay masks that data out of its props.

The solution is either to:

1. Pass `this.props.category` into `CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer`
2. Move the connection call `categories(first: …)` up to `CategoryItem`

Here's a link to a working Playground that implements option one: [facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=...](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20CategoryRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category(id%3A%20%24id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20paramDefinitions%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%20required%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'CategoryRoute'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItemSubCategoryList%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.category.categories.edges.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3CCategoryItemContainer%20key%3D%7Bnode.id%7D%20category%3D%7Bnode%7D%2F%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItemSubCategoryList%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20categories(first%3A%2010000)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemContainer.getFragment('category')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItem%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%20%20relay%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20category%20%3D%20this.props.category%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onMouseOver%3D%7Bthis.openCategory.bind(this)%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3E%7Bcategory.name%7D%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.relay.variables.expanded%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20key%3D%7Bcategory.id%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category%3D%7Bcategory%7D%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20openCategory()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20expanded%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItem%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20expanded%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20(variables)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment('category').if(variables.expanded)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BCategoryItemContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20CategoryRoute(%7B%20id%3A%20'2'%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20renderFetched%3D%7B(data)%20%3D%3E%20%3CCategoryItemContainer%20%7B...data%7D%2F%3E%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getCategory(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20id%2C%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bid%7D%60%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getCategories(category)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20cats%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%200%3B%20idx%20%3C%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cats.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20category.id%20%2B%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bcategory.id%20%2B%20idx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20cats%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20getCategory(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20categoryType%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20categoryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Category'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(category%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(getCategories(category)%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20categoryConnection%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Category'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20categoryType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20getCategory(args.id)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A)

Comment: Finally! Thank you! That was a lesson I was waiting for!

Comment: Steve, is it possible that you take a look at my next question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339060/how-to-get-data-from-the-local-graph ? Thank you.