# How to get data from the local graph?

Tags: recursion, reactjs, relayjs

I've got the component which displays the hierarchical data. It's a recursive data structure - a hierarchical classifier. Each category in the classifier consists of child categories and so on.

Here's the playground for it:

[Relay playground](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20CategoryRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category(id%3A%20%24id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20paramDefinitions%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%20required%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'CategoryRoute'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItemSubCategoryList%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.category.categories.edges.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3CCategoryItemContainer%20key%3D%7Bnode.id%7D%20category%3D%7Bnode%7D%2F%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItemSubCategoryList%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20categories(first%3A%2010000)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemContainer.getFragment('category')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItem%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%20%20relay%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20category%20%3D%20this.props.category%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onMouseOver%3D%7Bthis.openCategory.bind(this)%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3E%7Bcategory.name%7D%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.relay.variables.expanded%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20key%3D%7Bcategory.id%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category%3D%7Bcategory%7D%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20openCategory()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20expanded%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItem%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20expanded%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20(variables)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment('category').if(variables.expanded)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BCategoryItemContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20CategoryRoute(%7B%20id%3A%20'2'%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20renderFetched%3D%7B(data)%20%3D%3E%20%3CCategoryItemContainer%20%7B...data%7D%2F%3E%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getCategory(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20id%2C%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bid%7D%60%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getCategories(category)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20cats%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%200%3B%20idx%20%3C%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cats.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20category.id%20%2B%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bcategory.id%20%2B%20idx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20cats%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20getCategory(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20categoryType%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20categoryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Category'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(category%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(getCategories(category)%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20categoryConnection%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Category'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20categoryType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20getCategory(args.id)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A)

I've got a component showing this classifier in a third party html form. It is used to pick a category.

At some point in time a user will pick a category from this recursive classifier and I will have to get the full path of data that led to the current level. I mean if a user picks a category at the level 3 of the hierarchy, I must give back these data:

```
[root cat id, root cat name],
[level 1 cat id, level 1 cat name],
[level 2 cat id, level 2 cat name]
```

So when I catch the event of picking inside the component at the level 2 how can I get the full path from the root category from `Relay` store (from local graph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a React solution rather than a Relay one: how to access the path to a given node in the tree? I would synthesize a path, and pass it into your component.

```js
const path = [
  // The elements of the passed-in path.
  ...this.props.path,
  // A new path element using the details from this level.
  [this.props.catId, this.props.catName],
];
<MyNode path={path} onClick={() => alert(path)} />
```

Click here for a [working example](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20CategoryRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category(id%3A%20%24id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20paramDefinitions%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%20required%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'CategoryRoute'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItemSubCategoryList%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20React.PropTypes.array.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.category.categories.edges.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCategoryItemContainer%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3D%7Bnode.id%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category%3D%7Bnode%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3D%7Bthis.props.path%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItemSubCategoryList%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20categories(first%3A%2010000)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemContainer.getFragment('category')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20CategoryItem%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20React.PropTypes.object.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%20%20relay%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20React.PropTypes.array.isRequired%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20static%20defaultProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(props)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...props.path%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bprops.category.id%2C%20props.category.name%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20category%20%3D%20this.props.category%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onMouseOver%3D%7Bthis.openCategory%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20onClick%3D%7Bthis.selectCategory%7D%3E%7Bcategory.name%7D%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.relay.variables.expanded%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer%20key%3D%7Bcategory.id%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20category%3D%7Bcategory%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3D%7Bthis.state.path%7D%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20openCategory%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20e.stopPropagation()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20expanded%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20selectCategory%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20e.stopPropagation()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20alert('path%3A%20'%20%2B%20JSON.stringify(this.state.path))%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%20%0A%0Aconst%20CategoryItemContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(CategoryItem%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20expanded%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20(variables)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Category%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment('category').if(variables.expanded)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BCategoryItemContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20CategoryRoute(%7B%20id%3A%20'2'%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20renderFetched%3D%7B(data)%20%3D%3E%20%3CCategoryItemContainer%20%7B...data%7D%2F%3E%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getCategory(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20id%2C%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bid%7D%60%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getCategories(category)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20cats%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%200%3B%20idx%20%3C%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cats.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20category.id%20%2B%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%60catName%24%7Bcategory.id%20%2B%20idx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20cats%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20getCategory(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20categoryType%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20categoryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Category'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20categories%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(category%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(getCategories(category)%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20categoryConnection%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Category'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20categoryType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20categoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20getCategory(args.id)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0A).

Comment: Thank you! Your answers are the best! Do I get it right that the preferred way of getting the data from the local cache is like you say? I mean that Relay does not expose public API for examining the local graph, and it is always better to use props and synthesized data structures?

Comment: In general, data should flow from the top down; you should not be crawling up the graph from a child component to learn anything about your parents. There is another implementation where you could expose a `path` field in your schema, and build up the path in your `resolve()` methods. This will, of course, inflate the size of the network response, so the existing solution might be the best.